# Delay When Assigning String to UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I've come across a rather frustrating bug in my application. I am not sure if this has anything to do with the fact that I'm running Xcode 6.0, but I personally believe it has something to do with my code.

**The Problem:**
When I assign a couple Strings to `UILabel`s via a method meant to update data, it takes a good 30 seconds for the data to actually appear.

Sample code:

```
self.availHours.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", 24.0 - totalEventHours];
```

**What I've Tried:**
I've seeded my code with `NSLog`s to see if somehow the method really was taking that long to calculate and update the info. But according to the results from those, it finishes *well* before the content shows up. I've also commented out the logic and replaced it with a direct String assignment, still with the same results.

**Personal Conclusion:**
It's like the content is not reloading on re-assignment, is it necessary to somehow tell the view to make sure it has current data? If that's not necessary, then what are some reasons that this could happen?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you sure you are changing the label text on the main thread ? All UI updates should be done on the main thread.

Comment: Ah, I'm still pretty new to iOS (and programming in general) so I didn't even consider that. I put a break-point on the assignment line and sure enough, thread 4 UI edit, heh. I'll mark your answer as correct ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, you may want to try to set your label text on the main thread :

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

    // On the main thread
    self.availHours.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", 24.0 - totalEventHours];

}];
```